# Correct way to write ResponseEntity<T> with @RestController for Spring RESTful Api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/demo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setAge("12");
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I look into some documents and find some people will write as below:
`rResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(user);`

What's the difference between `new ResponseEntity<>(user, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);` and `ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(user);`? Which way is preferred? Thanks.

Comment: There's no recommended approach AFAIK, use the one you prefer. The second one via the builder is arguably easier to read, but it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Why can we write in ```ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(user);```? Is there any logic support here?

Comment: No, it just follows the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) with `.body(user)` eventually calling `new ResponseEntity<>(...)`.

Comment: I prefer to have the method return the type directly (`User` in your example) and use exceptions (e.g. `ResponseStatusException`) if something goes wrong. But as @sp00m already said it's a matter of taste really.

Comment: @slauth How should I modify the code if I use exceptions? Thanks.

Comment: @sp00m Thanks for help. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing a little example returning the `User` directly because IMHO it results in cleaner signatures:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/demo")
    public User test() {
        if (userDoesNotExist()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setAge("12");
        return user;
    }
}
```